# Please explain this Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I didn't write the following regex, and I'm trying to figure out what it does. I know that it must begin with policy-map and must have at least one space between policy-map and whatever comes next. But I'm stuck trying to figure out what the stuff inside the parenthesis means. I know that whatever it is, it has to be at the end of the line.

```
^policy-map\\s+([\\x21-\\x7e]{1,40})$
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the question then? "*Explain this regex in detail?*"

Comment: I highly recommend the following site: http://regex101.com/r/gV1hK3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

characters in range from hex 21 to hex 7e (basically printable, non-whitespace ascii) 1 to 40 times.

Comment: `[\\x21-\\x7e]` is commonly used to describe alphanumeric+special chars

Comment: This is the first time I've seen a regular expression written using hex. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 8):

`^` begin of string

`policy-map` constant

`\s+` spaces

`([\x21-\x7e]{1,40})` 1-40 symbols from \x21 to \x7e (i.e. all printable, non-whitespace ASCII characters including punctuation, upper and lower case letters and numbers)

`$` end of string

Answer (score 7):

```
^              Start of string
policy-map     "policy-map"
\\s+           One or more whitespace characters
(              Start of capture group 1
[\\x21-\\x7e]  From 1 to 40 characters in the range '\x21' to '\7E'
)              End of capture group 1
$              End of string
```