# Java - Capture optional field with regexp?

Tags: java, android, regex

I've a regex that correctly captures values from the result of a string.

regex is look like;

```
intGetHatSaatRenk_v22=anyType{SiraNo=(.*?); HatKodu=(.*?) ; GunTipi=(.*?); Gidis=(.*?); ? };
```

But the problem is the source is like;

```
intGetHatSaatRenk_v22=anyType{SiraNo=54; HatKodu=502 ; GunTipi=C; Gidis=12:00; RenkGidis=0000FF; }; 

intGetHatSaatRenk_v22=anyType{SiraNo=55; HatKodu=502 ; GunTipi=C; Gidis=12:07; }; intGetHatSaatRenk_v22=anyType{SiraNo=56; HatKodu=502 ; GunTipi=C; Gidis=12:14; };
```

as you can see there is an optional field that named **RenkGidis**, how can i get the value from RenkGidis if it's not null?

with the regex code that i wrote above, i can get if RenkGidis exists in group(4) like **12:00; RenkGidis=0000FF** but group(4) must be only **12:00**.

I hope that I could explain my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to make the last group [optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html):

```
intGetHatSaatRenk_v22=anyType\{SiraNo=([^;\s]*);\s+HatKodu=([^;\s]*)\s*;\s+GunTipi=([^;\s]*);\s+Gidis=([^;\s]*);(?:\s+RenkGidis=([^;\s]*);)?
```

As a Java string:

```
"intGetHatSaatRenk_v22=anyType\\{SiraNo=([^;\\s]*);\\s+HatKodu=([^;\\s]*)\\s*;\\s+GunTipi=([^;\\s]*);\\s+Gidis=([^;\\s]*);(?:\\s+RenkGidis=([^;\\s]*);)?"
```

At the last group `(` `?:` [prevents the group to be captured](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11530881/3110638) into output. `(` inside `)` catpured as usual.

Also changed `.*?` to `[^;\s]*` (negation of `[;\s]` -> any characters, that are no white-space or `;`)

---

As Alan mentioned in the comments, for not getting a `null` match for the optional part, e.g. just make `RenkGidis` optional and wrap the value in an alternation with nothing: `([^;\s]*;|)`

```
intGetHatSaatRenk_v22=anyType\{SiraNo=([^;\s]*);\s+HatKodu=([^;\s]*)\s*;\s+GunTipi=([^;\s]*);\s+Gidis=([^;\s]*);(?:\s+RenkGidis=)?([^;\s]*|)
```

As a Java string:

```
"intGetHatSaatRenk_v22=anyType\\{SiraNo=([^;\\s]*);\\s+HatKodu=([^;\\s]*)\\s*;\\s+GunTipi=([^;\\s]*);\\s+Gidis=([^;\\s]*);(?:\\s+RenkGidis=)?([^;\\s]*|)"
```

Comment: +1, but if there's no `RenkGidis` field `group(5)` will be null, so you need to check for that.

Comment: @Alan Moore Happy you like it, added an alternative :)

Comment: It was exactly what i wanted to do, i've learn a new thing on regexp. Thank you, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The regex could look like this

```
intGetHatSaatRenk_v22=anyType\{SiraNo=(.*?); HatKodu=(.*?) ; GunTipi=(.*?); Gidis=(.*?);( RenkGidis=.*?;\s*|\s*)\};
```

Group 5 will then be either " RenkGidis=0000FF;" or " ". You can then use a second regex to get 0000FF.