# Javascript REGEX to get 5 characters from a url

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I write a regex to get the 5 characters **572f0** from the below url?

The regex I built is **dep_id=([^&]*)** but this assumes that there will be a & after the value and I would like to just always match and retrive the 5 characters after **dep_id=**

https://test.com/Chat/test?language=en_US#dep_id=**572f0**&org_id=00Df0&

Comment: `dep_id=(.{5})` http://regex101.com/r/zM9cS1/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match 5 characters:

```
/dep_id=(.....)/
```

or

```
/dep_id=(.{5})/
```

If you want to match until & or the end:

```
/dep_id=([^&]+)/
```

Your initial regex was actually totally valid: it does not require a `&` to follow. It takes everything until a `&` or the end...

Comment: What purpose does the second parenthesized string serve? (?:&|$)

Comment: @AndrewShepherd, actually, it's not useful, and OP's first regex was totally valid, and the assumption he made that it required a `&` was incorrect.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd, it is a non-capturing group. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530862/regex-question-mark-and-colon)

Comment: @Adam: I'm sure Andrew asked about its *purpose* not about its syntactic meaning :-)

Comment: This works. Shorter version was posted in a comment above dep_id=(.{5})

Comment: @Adam: I didn't know it's syntactic meaning either, so thanks for the link :-)

Answer (score 3):

Not Regex, but

```
var x = "https://test.com/Chat/test?language=en_US#dep_id=572f0&org_id=00Df0&"
x.split("dep_id=")[1].substr(0,5)
```

Comment: An important note: this solution relies on presence of `dep_id=` in the string and fails with error otherwise.

Comment: @zerkms, that's accurate, but adding error handling would be trivial.

Comment: @Adam: indeed, but it will inflate the code, which will make the regex "better" solution. Btw, it is also not clear what to do if the `dep_id` parameter value is shorter than 5 characters. With regex it's easy to handle. With this code - it won't be.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the five chars directly, use this:

```
var myregex = /dep_id=([^#&\s]{5})/m;
var match = myregex.exec(str);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
} else {
    result = "";
}
```

**Explanation**

- `dep_id=` matches literal characters
- `([^#&\s]{5})` captures to Group 1 five chars that are not a `&`, url fragment delimiter `#` or whitespace

This retrieves the characters directly from the Group 1 capture.

Comment: I'm capped on rep for the day so I am just observing. +1 for the edit.

Comment: @hwnd the reason for `[^#&\s]` is that if we just take `.{5}`, we might start eating into another `&...`, or a url fragment `#...`, or past the end of the url.

Comment: @hwnd I hear you... I don't always trust problem descriptions 100%, so `[^#&\s]` works for me. :)